# ggraph - increase node size based on frequency

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggraph

Been reading Tidytext Mining with R by Julia Silge and David Robinson - https://www.tidytextmining.com/nasa.html - and stumped on how to have the node size adjust in relation to frequency (n). Tried the following code...

```
 library(widyr)
 set.seed(1234)
 title_word_pairs %>%
 filter(n >= 250) %>%
 graph_from_data_frame() %>%
 ggraph(layout = "fr") +
 geom_edge_link(aes(edge_alpha = n, edge_width = n), edge_colour = 
 "royalblue") +
 geom_node_point(aes(size = n)) + scale_size(range = c(2,10)) +
 geom_node_text(aes(label = name), repel = TRUE,
            point.padding = unit(0.2, "lines")) +
 theme_void()
```

...and receive this error...

```
 Error: Column `size` must be a 1d atomic vector or a list
 Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that this frequency `n` is for *edges*, not *vertices*. So `geom_edge_link` finds `n` because `n` is an edge attribute, while `geom_node_point` doesn't find `n` because it's not among vertex attributes.

So then we wish to construct another variable that would actually be the vertex frequency.

```
subt <- title_word_pairs %>%
  filter(n >= 250)
vert <- subt %>% gather(item, word, item1, item2) %>%
  group_by(word) %>% summarise(n = sum(n))

subt %>%
  graph_from_data_frame(vertices = vert) %>%
  ggraph(layout = "fr") +
  geom_edge_link(aes(edge_alpha = n, edge_width = n), edge_colour = "royalblue") +
  geom_node_point(aes(size = n)) + scale_size(range = c(2,10)) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name), repel = TRUE, point.padding = unit(0.2, "lines")) +
  theme_void()
```

Here `subt` is the same as before, then `vert` contains two columns: vertices (words) and their frequency in `subt` as a sum or relevant edge frequencies. Lastly, I added `vertices = vert` as to pass this vertex attribute.

Comment: thanks the help. I was able to repurpose the logic to a project I'm currently developing.